# Converting OOo macros to Excel macros

Tags: excel, openoffice.org, file-conversion

I have an OpenDocument spreadsheet with macros in StarBasic/OOoBasic that I want to convert into an Excel spreadsheet, with the StarBasic macros translated to VBA. While OpenOffice.org claims to have the ability to translate VBA macros to StarBasic and back, my attempts to have OOo convert these original StarBasic macros to VBA have all failed.

Is there any guaranteed way to get these macros moved to VBA and Excel, without completely rewriting them? It seems that OOo will only turn StarBasic macros to VBA if they originated in that form.

Comment: Can you provide an example of something that is failing?  As you mention, they are designed to be compatible with VBA.

Comment: I never said anything about VBA compatability... OOo can translate macros from VBA to StarBasic and back, but it refuses to translate original StarBasic macros to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of OpenOffice.org 3.0, there's nothing that can be done but rewrite the macros. Fortunately VBA and StarBasic are similar enough that the only work that needs to be done is changing over the application document model.